# Asterisk with MySQL

Tags: mysql, asterisk

How does Asterisk saves it's data? Does it use flat files, SQLite, or a database like MySQL by default?

Can I change the way data is being stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about CDRs (Call Detail Records) then it looks like it uses a CSV file as default, but you can change it to MySQL or many other formats if you wish:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+billing

Answer (score 1):

The question is not specific enough. Asterisk uses different methods to store data for different stuff.

If you are referring to the astdb: Till Asterisk 1.8 they use Berkeley DB. Beginning with Asterisk 10.0 they use SQLite. Have a look at https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SQLite3+astdb+back-end

Answer (score 0):

You can also use php agi to communicate to php webserver and then to mysql...it's most commonly use method to communicate to mysql DB...